# Getting negative numbers from my implementation of alpha centrality

Tags: python, numpy, graph, igraph

Alpha centrality isn't implemented in software packages easily accessible to me (using R-igraph is not an option), so I went about implementing it myself.  From the Wikipedia page, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_centrality) it would seem to be very easy to implement in terms of matrix algebra, given the adjacency matrix.  So I whipped up a  [simple graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f9vE.png) in igraph and implemented the formula on the Wikipedia page using numpy.  The code is shown as follows:

```
import igraph as ig
from numpy import matrix
import numpy as np

# Build the graph shown in the question above

graph = ig.Graph()
vertices = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
graph.add_vertices(vertices)
edges = [('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('A', 'E'), ('A', 'F'), ('B', 'C'), ('B', 'D'), ('B', 'E'), ('B', 'F')]
graph.add_edges(edges)
adjacency_matrix = graph.get_adjacency()

# Some constants needed for alpha centrality algorithm, picking some simple options for those constants.

alpha_cent_weights = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
alpha = 1

#Converting data structures to numpy matrices

numpy_adjacency = matrix(adjacency_matrix.data)
numpy_weights = matrix(alpha_cent_weights)
numpy_weights = numpy_weights.T
adjacency_matrix_size = numpy_adjacency.shape[0]
identity_matrix = np.identity(adjacency_matrix_size)
alpha_cent = (identity_matrix - alpha * numpy_adjacency.T).I.dot(numpy_weights)
```

However, when I run this code, the values in alpha_cent are all negative, which is not something I expect for a centrality measure.  My program calculates the alpha centralities as (approximately)...

A: -.714, B: -.714, C: -.419, D: -.419, E: -.419, F: -.419.

At first I thought it was just a matter of a missing minus sign, but when I changed alpha_cent_weights to [1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1] the calculated alpha centralities become:

A: -1.86, B: .142, C: -.714, D: -.714, E: -.714, F: -.714

In this case, taking the absolute value would make no sense because I would expect B to have a higher value from both its position in the network and the extra weighting from alpha_cent_weights.

In my attempts to solve this problem, I have dug into some scholarly articles (including the one listed on Wikipedia's alpha centrality page), searched Google for "Alpha centrality," broken the calculation of "alpha_cent" in the above code down step-by-step, and asked a colleague at work for help.

Is there something wrong my code?  Is there something wrong with my understanding of alpha centrality, or centrality in general?

Comment: Did you try to use R-igraph to verify your numbers?

Comment: Getting R working and rewriting this code in R represents A LOT of work for me because I don't have complete control over my software environment and my R coding is very weak.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The wikipedia article claims that when _alpha_ is very large, then alpha centrality converges to eigenvector centrality. I do not see how this could happen. There may be a mistake in the formula.

Comment: After some additional digging, I found the following discussion on Katz centrality, which contains a very similar term to alpha centrality:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292218/parameter-for-katz-centrality-of-a-graph

It seems to suggest that for Katz centrality, the free parameter should be smaller than 1/lambda, where lambda is the largest eigenvalue for the adjacency matrix.  I tried setting alpha = .1 in my code, and the answers seem to make more sense now.  However, if that's true, alpha centrality may be unsuitable for my problem as I won't know the eigenvalues in advance

Comment: @alex getting R working cannot be easier. You can even do it online: https://rdrr.io/snippets/  and then e.g. `library(igraph); g <- sample_gnp(40, 4/40); alpha_centrality(g)`